# Count a lines in a RichTextBox wp7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have some trouble with RichTextBox on WP7. I want get number of lines in this control or anything else that will give me information about location of the text on the current screen. thanks.

Comment: Couting the `Environment.NewLine` wont give you the total lines?

Comment: I tried this way:
 `for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            {

                if (s[i].ToString() == Environment.NewLine)
                {
                    lines++;
                }
 
            }`
but its not working good

Answer (score 0):

You can split a string to create an array of strings. For example:

```
string[] lines = yourRichTextBox.Text.Split(new[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

// lines.Count will give you total number of lines
```

I have added StringSplitOptions enumeration parameter to ignore empty values that would usually end up in an array. You might want to avoid this if you need to get a true count of number of lines.

Comment: I tried this way too, but get just 1 and its not right answer.

Comment: In that case it seems that you don't more than one line break.

Comment: yes, its right, I looked in the debug variable that contains the text and did not find it line breaks. but obviously the text in my control is transferred to the next line.

Comment: Yes it is transfered because it is wrapped into a new line. That does not really count as a new line.